# Replacing scriptProcessorNode with AudioWorklet

Tags: audio-recording, web-audio-api, voice-recording

I am working on recording microphone input from the user and processing it. The problem is that I am using scriptProcessorNode to process data, but [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor) it said that is has been deprecated and replaced with [AudioWorklet](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet).The problem is that there is no clear way to replace this functionality with AudioWorklet, and from all of the [example projects with AudioWorklets](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/#design-pattern) from Google, none of them is doing anything with microphone input. Is there a way to replace this code with Audio Worklet? Here is the code that "should" be replaced.

```
    // Connect analyser
    this.options.source.connect(this.analyser);
    // Create ScriptProcessorNode
    this.scriptProcessorNode = this.options.context.createScriptProcessor(this.options.bufferLen, numChannels, numChannels);
    // Connect scriptProcessorNode (Theretically, not required)
    this.scriptProcessorNode.connect(this.options.context.destination);
    // Create callback to update/analyze floatFrequencyData
    var self = this;
    this.scriptProcessorNode.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
        self.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(self.floatFrequencyData);
        self.update();
        self.store(event);
        self.monitor();
    };
    // Connect scriptProcessorNode
    this.options.source.connect(this.scriptProcessorNode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple example of creating an AudioWorkletProcessor. You can check it [here](https://bitbucket.org/alvaro_maceda/notoono/src/stackoverflow/). It only works on Chromium, Firefox don't have support for AudioWorklet yet.

It's an example I've prepared to show a webpack error I'm having, so please check only the source code. If you run the project it will fail unless you comment audio-meter.js line 8 and uncomment line 11. The file audio-meter.worker.js is duplicated with the same content.

Comment: I cannot access the link you attached

Comment: Hey, I was having some issues and I didn't really have time to debug it. I see audio-meter.js is trying to import audio-meter.worker.js but audio-meter.worker.js is not providing any default export. I am trying to test the site on localhost.

Comment: My bad, it works actually. What are you doing with the audio input?

Comment: Still nothing, but the idea is to generate a rxjs stream with the rms of the input. I'm trying to figure out how to test this. I'v seen this: https://github.com/mohayonao/web-audio-test-api but it doesn't support AudioWorklets. All ideas are wellcome. You have the original project here: https://bitbucket.org/alvaro_maceda/notoono but don't expect too much.