# Connect to AudioWorklet instead of ScriptProcessor when recording

Tags: web-audio-api, audio-worklet, scriptprocessor

I need to convert my ScriptProcessor logic to an AudioWorklet. The ScriptProcessor process is very easy and only a few lines of code, but I'm having a hard time converting it over to an AudioWorklet.

Here is my current process (the stream comes from userMedia):

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(0, 1, 1);
microphone.connect(processor);
processor.connect(context.destination);
```

and then I send the data to a worker:

```
processor.onaudioprocess = function (event) {
var array = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
realTimeWorker.postMessage({cmd: 'encode', buf: array})
};
```

I just need the AudioWorklet to process the data in the same way the ScriptProcessor does it, and then send the same data to the worker.

How could I convert this process to an AudioWorklet?

Comment: did you try the solution in this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097768/replacing-scriptprocessornode-with-audioworklet